# How to calculate average rating in excel with excluding blank cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to **calculate average rating** in excel with **excluding blank cells**?

In other way

- if cells is empty --> not calculate rating
- if 0 or greater than 0 to 5 --> calculate rating

then calculate average ratings.

Comment: Have you tried averageif() or averageifs() ?

Comment: If `A1 = 1` and `B1 = 2` then `=AVERAGE(A1:XFD1)` results in `1.5` proving that empty cells are excluded. If you do `C1 = =""`  and `D1='`, you will additionally prove that blank cells are excluded. So what is the question?

Comment: Read the documentation. `AVERAGE` ignores blank cells.  What is your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your range includes values of less than 0 and/or larger than 5 and empty, but you only want to calculate value from 0 to 5?
I think you'd better use pair of SUMIFS and COUNTIFS, with set of your conditions (>=0, <=5, not blank...).

For example, assumed your value range B1:B6: [image]

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B6,B1:B6,">=0",B1:B6,"<=5")/COUNTIFS(B1:B6,">=0",B1:B6,"<=5")
```

This give out result of average of 2.5

And please note that COUNTIFS or AVERAGE... they do not count empty cells by default.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will average the contents of a range of cell for cells with values greater than 0. Just expand this to cover all the ranges.

=SUM(A1:A10)/COUNTIF(A1:A10,">0")